# LISTAGG function: Short string return ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long

Tags: regex, overflow, oracle12c, listagg

I have a query to extract the email domain from a column that maintained with multiple email addresses. The column value is aaa@yahoo.com, bbb@hotmail.com, and the column size is  VARCHAR2(3500 CHAR)

Below query used listagg function to extract the domains and prefixed with regular expression:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
LISTAGG( CHR(91)||'a-zA-Z0-9._%-'||CHR(93)||'+' ||REGEXP_SUBSTR(EMAIL_STRING,'@' || CHR(91) || '^,' 
|| CHR(93) ||'+', 1, LEVEL), ',')
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LEVEL) AS  USER_EMAILS_DOMAIN
FROM EMAIL_PARAMETER WHERE NAME='UserEmails'
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(EMAIL_STRING,'@'||CHR(91)||'^,'||CHR(93)||'+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
```

Expected outcome: [a-zA-Z0-9.*%-]+@yahoo.com,[a-zA-Z0-9.*%-]+@hotmail.com

The string is within 4000 characters, however Oracle return `ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long`

I tried to use `LISTAGG` with `ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE` option, it returns a long string with the second email,  bbb@hotmail.com keeps on repeating.

I also try on `XMLTAGG`, also I'm getting a very long string with both emails are repeating.

```
select rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e,CHR(91)||'a-zA-Z0-9._%-'||CHR(93)||'+' || EMAIL_STRING,',').extract('//text()') order by REGEXP_SUBSTR(EMAIL_STRING,'@' || CHR(91) || '^,' || CHR(93) ||'+', 1, LEVEL)).getclobval(),',') USER_EMAILS_DOMAIN
FROM EMAIL_PARAMETER WHERE NAME='UserEmails' 
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(EMAIL_STRING,'@'||CHR(91)||'^,'||CHR(93)||'+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Hi there, please provide us with some test data please

Comment: @ekochergin, i mentioned the data in question.  The email_string column value is aaa@yahoo.com, bbb@hotmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if `DISTINCT` doesn't do what you hoped it would.

**First** select all distinct domains, **then** apply `listagg` to the result.

Simplified:

```
select listagg(domain, ',') within group (order by domain) final_result  --> 2. aggregation
from 
     (select distinct regexp_substr(email_string, ...) as domain         --> 1. distinct domains
      from email_parameter
     )
```